# Word2Vec based on Hierarchies

Tags: nltk, word2vec

This is an conceptual/algorithm question - on how to move a hierarchical word structure into Word2Vec

I have (luckily) a well structured source, with a string and the hierarchical meaning of this string above/below. Now I would like to make the Word2Vec learn close terminologies. E.g. an entry can look like:

- String N+1: steering assembly
- String N: wheel
- String N-1: tire, wheel rim, bolts

My experience with Word2Vec is only on floating text, where the analysis is running over the text.
Any directions would be very much appreciated.